# Direction from a normalized vector

Tags: math

I guess this is more of a math question, but please bear with me :)

I have a vector defined as follows:

```
 var direction:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(_target.x - this.x, _target.y - this.y);
 direction.Normalize();
```

with which I use

```
   _body.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(direction.x*2, direction.y*2));
```

to propel a body forward to a target.

My question is how would I be able to find *the relative position of* my body. For example, from that normalized vector, how can I tell whether the target is on the right, left, up or down?

I would like to get the "position" of my body relative to the target using a normalized direction vector. How would that be possible?

As an aside, I only need the relative position to be normalized to the four cardinal directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider some cases, and try to form an intuitive understanding -

1) Target at (2, 2) and body at (-1, 1) with respect to the global coordinates

Your direction vector is (3, 1). Since both components are positive, The target is to the right and above of the body.

1) Target at (2, -2) and body at (-1, 1) with respect to the global coordinates

Your direction vector is (3, -3). Since the x-component is positive, the target is to the right of the body. Since the y-component is negative, the target is below the body.

These will become evident to you if you plot these points on a 2D axis, and calculate the direction vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix transformation here:

```
   _target.y-this.y   _target.x-this.x
 - _target.x-this.x   _target.y-this.y
```

will rotate your vector (and scale it by x^2 + y^2, but that doesn't matter) to the x-axis. Apply the same transformation to the location of the body, and then use the sign of the two coordinates to identify which quadrant it is in relative to the original vector.